# How to ensure my Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku is updated with latest code in my GitHub repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku

I'm a newbie to RoR, GitHub and Heroku, so I'm still trying to figure this out.

I've made changes to some file in my private GitHub repo, and saved changes ("commit"). I was expecting to see those changes reflect immediately on the app's URL, but I see no change. Is there a time delay, or am I doing things wrong?

I edited the sourcecode from within GitHub itself. I also used Aptana as well.

Comment: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to push your changes to your heroku repo manually like this:

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that after going through the heroku docs.

Answer (score 3):

you have to push your changes to heroku

```
git push heroku master
```

take a look at [Getting Started with Heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart)

Comment: Thank you! I was going through the docs and realized that that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Total Git / Heroku n00b here.

Just wanted to chime in to say that before running the push command, I had to first run a pull request..

```
git pull
```

Multiple commits had been made, but just running the push command wasn't showing changes on the Heroku app. I think the reason being was that the updated files were not committed by me, but by someone else remotely. However I'm the one who set up and am managing the Heroku app. So, I had to pull the committed files onto my local setup before I could push them to Heroku.

Thanks go to [willglynn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026671/willglynn) for the clue-in via his answer on another thread:

- [pushed to heroku but no changes to app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927590/pushed-to-heroku-but-no-changes-to-app)