# how to update application on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am new to heroku. 
I created a very simple rails app, and deployed it to heroku.

how can I commit the changes to git?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ensure my Ruby on Rails app hosted on Heroku is updated with latest code in my GitHub repo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069554/how-to-ensure-my-ruby-on-rails-app-hosted-on-heroku-is-updated-with-latest-code-i)

Comment: +1 even though I gave the answer.  4 words was just easier to type thatn find it and link it, sry to the mods :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to perform:

```
git add .
git commit -m "updated the header and footer"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: when I do this It looks like it reinstalling rails all over again. isnt it a way to updated only the changed files?

Comment: this is how heroku works (gems are pushed each time).  You can create a slug and push that which will rapid deploy.  Heroku has a tip article about this: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler

Comment: I tried to do this, but I've since renamed the app, so it no longer recognizes the push key. Or maybe there's a different reason for that. I don't know, I've only done this once.

Comment: But how does heroku know which website/project do you refer to?

Comment: @munmunbb It is configured as a git remote. If you run `git remote -v` inside your project you'll see something like: `heroku https://git.heroku.com/...`

Answer (score 5):

I hope this would help.
Three steps:

```
git add .    
git commit -m "make changes"    
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a git push

```
git push heroku master
```

Comment: when I type this it says -"everything up-to-date" which is not true. Dont I need to commit the changes to git first?

Comment: Type `git status` . Read carefully the results.

Comment: For anyone experiencing same issue, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27632847/2501304) solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

This was what I did to update mine.. hope it will work for you
first yo have to run dis command to check modified files
`git status`
Take note of the modified files (it could be a path or just a file name)
`git add <file name or path>`
run the above command for all the modified file and then commit
`git commit -m "your message"` and now push
`git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

This could be strange but I've got error with **git push heroku master**. However it worked as below and I've managed to update my app.

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are deploying via GitHub then you will have to add,

```
git push origin master
```

and then use

```
git push heroku master
```