# Heroku not loading newly committed CSS into my node app

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku, github

I have simply updated my main.css file locally, committed it to github and my changes are not showing. I have confirmed these changes should in fact be working by editing the same file with the same small style change in Chrome's developer console. I have checked my github repo and it has all my code up to date. I even made a small HTML change in the same commit and that change was made in the live heroku app. I have tried clearing all heroku/github and chrome caches to make sure that an old CSS file wasn't being used but this is not the case.

Why won't the CSS load? Is this a Heroku problem?

Comment: Are you seeing any deploy errors? Have you looked into the suggestions here? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22617294/3215966

Comment: No that's what is so strange. I actually saw that post and had really high hopes for it working but it didn't :(

Comment: have you tried clearing cache or opening page in private browsing mode?

Answer (score 0):

Check the path set thoroughly  and reload it.

Comment: But this is the same file that I am editing in the developer console so it is clearly loaded. Changes just aren't being deployed

Comment: can you display the code so that I can get the exact view

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue happened to me - it was to do with npm. Every now and then, the path to my dependencies goes awry and I need to reset it with this string in the command line.

`export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH"`