# Why doesn't the code on Heroku get updated after updating the code on GitHub?

Tags: reactjs, django, heroku

I'm making a simple TODO app and want to upload it to HEROKU.
But after I updated the code on Github, heroku code remained the same.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600382/heroku-is-not-updating-my-code) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947406/git-push-heroku-master-says-everything-up-to-date-but-the-app-is-not-current) and the other answers but nothing changed.

Site Code

[image]

Code on github [here](https://github.com/Anderli-dev/todo-app/blob/master/src/components/CSRFToken.js). As you can see `console.log()` on site has not disappeared

[Heroku site](https://my-dj-react-simple-todo-app.herokuapp.com/)

I even tried to re-create the app on Heroku but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's GitHub integration [has been disabled for over a month](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413) as part of a security response. It appears that it will remain disabled for another week or so:

> Based on current progress, we plan to complete our investigation by May 30, 2022
>
> …
>
> We know you are waiting for us to re-enable our integration with GitHub, and we've committed to you that we will only do so following a security review. We will post more information to [status.heroku.com](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413) when it is available.

You should have received emails about this from Salesforce ([Heroku's parent company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku)) on or around April 15 and May 4, 2022.

At the moment, your only option is to deploy using some other method. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71892543/354577) for more details. The answers there suggest some alternative ways to deploy your code.

(Your Heroku password was also forcefully reset; if you have not yet changed it you'll need to do that when you log back in.)

Comment: Thx, but I used Heroku CLI to deploy.

Comment: @IvanS, then what does "I updated the code on Github" mean in your question, and why would that have any impact on Heroku?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I updated code on github and after that code is updated on heroku, right? Maybe there's something I don't understand or don't know

Comment: @IvanS, that's how the (currently unavailable) GitHub integration I describe in my answer works, when enabled and configured. But you replied to my answer saying you use the Heroku CLI to deploy. I'm not clear on what workflow you are trying to use.