# Update an app - Heroku - doesn't work

Tags: python, heroku, web-applications

I'm starting with Heroku - Python. I have created an application as is described in this tutorial: [tutorial on Heroku web](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#set-up). Everything worked fine, I typed `heroku open` and webapp said *Hello from Python!*. So I tried to find where is *Hello from Python!* text situated and changed it to *Hello from Python! update* to learn how to update the code.

I tried to type `git push heroku master` as is described here: [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170225/how-to-update-application-on-heroku) but get the same problem - *everything up-to-date* which is not true.

Have you any ideas how to update the code? What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You must commit your changes to your local git repository before pushing them to the heroku's repository. 
You can do it with the bash command:

```
git commit -m "comment"
```

After if it doesn't work check if your python module is actually under version control:

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

And eventually you can add modules to version control:

```
git add <filename>
```