# pushed to heroku but no changes to app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I used the following three commands to push the changes to an already existing app but the changes are not being reflected

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "changes"
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
$ git push heroku master
```

And I get:

```
To git@heroku.com:sleepy-oasis-7771.git ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:sleepy-oasis-7771.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

and no changes are reflected in the app

Comment: Check this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831129/failed-to-push-some-refs-to-githeroku-commyapp-git

Answer (score 2):

Your push was `! [rejected]`. That's why no changes take effect.

As the message indicates:

```
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

This refers you to further documentation, visible on your local machine or [online](http://www.unixlore.net/cgi-bin/man/man2html?git-push+1#lbAL). Again, as the message indicates, a `git pull` (and its resulting merge) will fix this issue.

One way to avoid this problem is by using a [rebase workflow](http://randyfay.com/node/91) instead of a merge workflow. Do your development in a feature branch, and when you're ready to merge, pull master, rebase the feature branch, re-run your test suite, and *then* merge.

Also, please read your error messages.